# How to scroll the fixed content in CSS and HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, layout

There is a heading bar and menu bar in my site , and both of them used the position : fixed to fix on screen.

This is the result I would like to achieve:

http://www.kraphicstudio.com/LLR/index.html

notice that the menu bar "event about..." can scroll if I have reduce the size of the screen

However, this is my current website:

```
kotechweb.com/love_run/
```

The problem are:

1 . both heading bar and menu bar can not scroll. 
2. the heading bar has some empty space at left hand size

I have attempt added the

`overflow-x:visible` to the bar but there is no effect.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Please add the relevant code to the post.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have specified the height/width of the div in which the menu bar is placed in percentage. Thus if you reduce the screen-size, the div will also reduce. If you want the scroll bar to appear, you must specify the width in cm/px/pt.

Comment: yes ,  using absolute instead of fixed solved the problem. Thanks a lot